# Magento 2.4.5 - Deadlock on table catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica and index stuck

Tags: php, mysql, magento, indexing

The index "catalog_product_category" is stuck and the table "catalog_category_product_index_store1" is locked.

This is crashing down our website.

What we should do to have our indexes running correctly again and identify why it got stuck.

[Index stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyw3e.png)

[Locked table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEv5m.png)

The paliative solution until now is:
Reboot our application and RDS.

Comment: Why are you truncating the table?

Comment: We are not truncating the table on our own, I think it's one of Magento's processes.

Answer (score 0):

Find out why Magento is `TRUNCATEing` a table.  If possible, avoid using whatever is involved.  If that is not possible, then jettison Magento.

A possible situation is "replacing" the contents of a table.  For example, if you get a new set of values for `catelog...replica`, you could use `TRUNCATE`, but this is much better:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE catelog...replica;
load the new data into `new`
RENAME TABLE catelog...replica TO old,
             new TO catelog...replica;
DROP TABLE old;
```

No `TRUNCATE`, no downtime (except a *tiny* amount for the `RENAME`), no time during which the table is empty (and being refilled), etc.